# C++ Make a banlist with std::vector or std::map

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, vector, std

I am trying to write a small banlist with std::vector/std::map. But i don't know how it should work yet...

Here is how "BanList" is build on Networking.h:

```
static std::vector<int, std::string>BanList;
```

- Int is for the ID
- string for the target IP

This is a snippet of my Networking.cpp (Where the target gets added to the banlist)

```
if (boost::contains(dataPackage.data, needle1) && boost::contains(dataPackage.data, needle2))
{
        // All okay here - Let's jump over & let the thread handle the action
}
else
{
    //e.g. BanList.addTarget(Auto-Incremented ID, TargetsIP);
    break;
}
```

So there on the line where's // e.g BanList.addTarget(int, string); how should it work with std::vector or std::map? How can i create now a list full of the targets? To get the IP is not my problem! The problem is how to set the ID automatically and add then the target to the list... Already now thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is here. If you want to know how to use maps, then you should see the [the online reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

In your particular case, if you use the map:

```
static std::map<int, std::string> banList;
banList[id] = ipAddress;
```

I don't know why you would want to map ints to strings for a ban list. But this is how you do it.

For a vector, you can't have key/value pairs unless you're pushing a `std::pair` object. For that though, you almost always will want to use a map.

To add to a vector, use `vec.push_back(item)`.

You can find almost all of this on online references.

Answer (score 0):

Carefuly read the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)'s template parameters. `std::string` is not a valid allocator for `int` :)

This would be closer to `std::map<int, std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> BanList;
```

Learn the rest about `std::vector`/`std::pair` or `std::map` from the reference/your favorite book. It isn't worth explaining it here (and there is not enough space for it).

If `TargetsIP` is something like `std::vector<std::string>`, you will need to iterate through it and append elements to `BanList` in a loop.

Comment: Thank you! :-) This helped me ^-^